# C++ ASM Inline how to use struct members in ASM?

Tags: c++, data-structures, assembly, inline-assembly

I have the following

```
struct john {
    int oldA;
    int A;
} myJohn;
DWORD gotoAddressBack = 0x00401000;

void __declspec( naked ) test(void) {
    __asm {
        MOV myJohn.oldA, DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x77C]
        MOV DWORD PTR DS:[ESI+0x77C], myJohn.A
        JMP gotoAddressBack
    }
}
```

You can tell that both MOV's generate the `error C2415: improper operand type.`

As you can see what I want to do is store [ESI+0x77C]'s value into myJohn.oldA

Then I want to replace the same [ESI+0x77C]'s value with myJohn.A

Comment: Why do you have to deal with DS?

Comment: Well the 4 byte value is stored in memory and `ESI` keeps changing every second to a new value, before ESI changes I must replace the location of ESI+0x77C's value to my own... and store the old value for reference purposes. If you are interested the test() function is strapped to be called by a little patch in the target

Comment: I don't know why it's DS.. thats how it was before I wanted to patch the register to a different value. It works.. if I just instead of myJohn.A put like `12345` instead it would apply the changes perfectly.                                                                                              If anyone can tell me how to do this without the structures.. such as just using `int oldA = 0;` `int A = 0;` that would also be useful.. doesn't matter to me.. just structure is a little more packaged/neater for me

Comment: Inline assembly... people, why do you do this to yourselves?

Comment: @Daniel how else can you apply a patch in real-time to a software which isn't open sourced.. ? Can't use memory editing as the location where I am applying this patch is kinda temporary (disposed)..

Comment: @Daniel: There are some places that you really have to use inline-assembly. If you have never encountered such situations, I assume you have not pushed edges yet.

Comment: I just find it's usually much easier to simply code the entire function in pure assembly. But you're probably right, I'm sure there are cases where this is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no memory/memory operand for `MOV` instruction. You should use a register for such usages. This is something like that:

```
void __declspec( naked ) test(void) {
    __asm {
        MOV EAX, DWORD PTR [ESI+0x77C]
        MOV myJohn.oldA, EAX

        MOV EAX, myJohn.A
        MOV DWORD PTR [ESI+0x77C], EAX

        JMP gotoAddressBack
    }
}
```

BTW, I really suspect that you really have to deal with segment registers under modern OSes (due to virtual memory, i.e. you can use direct addresses). You should check your code after above changes.

Comment: Yup Thanks OSman Turan, just tested and yup that works perfectly.